# How to list file names in order using python

Tags: python

I am fetching all list of file names from a directory
But when i sort it is not sorted according to the number wise file names in `final.txt` file

**My Python code :**

```
pth=r'/d/demo'
fname=glob.glob(pth+"/['ABC']*.txt")
nlist='/d/bk/final.txt'

fname.sort()

for i in fname:
    file=os.path.basename(i)
    nlist.write(file+os.linesep)
```

**The above code output coming in below format in** `final.txt` **file**

```
ABC1.txt
ABC11.txt
ABC10.txt
ABC2.txt
ABC3.txt
ABC4.txt
ABC5.txt
ABC6.txt
ABC7.txt
ABC8.txt
ABC9.txt
ABC13.txt
ABC12.txt
```

**Expected output in below format :**

```
ABC1.txt
ABC2.txt
ABC3.txt
ABC4.txt
ABC5.txt
ABC6.txt
ABC7.txt
ABC8.txt
ABC9.txt
ABC10.txt
ABC11.txt
ABC12.txt
ABC13.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is named [natural sort order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order). If using external modules is ok in your case then you might harness [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) (which might be installing simply by `pip install natsort`) following way:

```
import natsort
fname = ["ABC1.txt","ABC11.txt","ABC10.txt","ABC2.txt","ABC3.txt"]
fname = natsort.natsorted(fname)
print(fname)
```

output

```
['ABC1.txt', 'ABC2.txt', 'ABC3.txt', 'ABC10.txt', 'ABC11.txt']
```

Note that `natsort.natsorted` is supposed to be used like `sorted` rather than `.sort`, i.e. it does return new `list`.

Comment: any other approach apart from natsort